# Online Presence with Wikipedia

Tags: resume, job-search, online-presence

I am currently a senior in college in the job hunting phase. I have a rather significant online presence with an upcoming website, LinkedIn profile, StackOverflow Careers profile, etc... I also have an (shameless plug) impressive resume which almost always attracts attention whenever I distribute it.

However, in an effort to always improve, is writing a Wikipedia article on myself a good idea, should someone look up my name? Would that be a good place to elaborate on details, awards, background, etc... which I would not normally put on a resume? Since Wikipedia is an online encyclopedia, basically, people would more likely go there to actually read about me. This is not quite the same on a resume where real estate is precious, and on a profile website where less words and more pictures are what people expect.

I understand the wiki-style editing of any entry on Wikipedia is open for anyone to edit, so that is something to consider.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you a notable person per Wikipedia's rules?

Comment: Keep in mind that you are forbidden to write an article about yourself on Wikipedia. Don't have a link to back it up, but I will find it if you don't believe me :) .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wikipedia is open for anyone to edit. That does **not** mean that it is "anything goes" as far as writing about anything at all.

If you are a college senior hunting for a job, I absolutely 100% guarantee you that any article you create about yourself will be deleted for being a non-notable subject.

Have a read of [Wikipedia:Notability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability). In particular, section 1, the [General Notability Guideline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability#General_notability_guideline).

> "If a topic has received significant coverage in reliable sources that
>   are independent of the subject, it is presumed to be suitable for a
>   stand-alone article or list."

What this means is, basically, once you start getting books or articles in major publications written about you, then you're notable enough for a Wikipedia article. I'm guessing that probably hasn't happened yet.

Also, read [Wikipedia:Autobiography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Autobiography) (thanks [sharth](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/8479/sharth) for point this one out). The takeaway there is:

> "Writing an autobiography on Wikipedia is strongly discouraged, unless
>   your writing has been approved by other editors in the community.
>   Editing a biography about yourself should only be done in clear-cut
>   cases."

Furthermore, have a look at [Wikipedia:Conflict of Interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Conflict_of_interest). The brief summary there is..

> "when advancing outside interests is more important to an editor than
>   advancing the aims of Wikipedia, that editor stands in a conflict of
>   interest."

Translation: if you're writing an article for reasons of self-promotion, not because you think the world would benefit from having this article in a free online encyclopedia, then expect to have people take a dim view of it.

But, after all this.. if you *do* have significant enough achievements to justify a Wikipedia article, then yes, it will be extremely impressive to potential employers! You'll be in the same league as the few hundred people in, for instance, [Category:American computer programmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_computer_programmers)!

Comment: Thanks for your very effective answer. I'll just add the OP is most likely not making full use of LinkedIn's features. Most people simply resurgitate their resumes on LinkedIn, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer provides an even better and answers an even more important than what I had asked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another thing to consider is that if the article about you is deleted, there'll be a record of it.  Do you really think that `This page has been deleted: Article about a real person, which does not indicate the importance or significance of the subject` would be seen as a ringing endorsement of your skills?

Comment: @sharth thanks, good tip! I have added that to the answer.